# Send multiple emails from a database using PHP

Tags: php, database, email

I need help in sending multiple emails from database using [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). I have a code that work, but it can only allow one email in it. Is there some way to modify it to help me send multiple ones?

```
<?
    require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail  = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();

    //Gmail configuration
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the server
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = "******@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = "785123nick";            // GMAIL password
        $prize = "lol";
    //End Gmail

    $mail->From       = "from@email.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "Jetstar";
    $mail->Subject    = "Order Redemption";
    $mail->MsgHTML("You have bought  " . $prize . " Print this and collect it at our office.");

    //$mail->AddReplyTo("reply@email.com","reply name"); //They answer here, optional
    $mail->AddAddress("your-email","name to");
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    if(!$mail->Send()) { //To see if we return a message or a value bolean
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else  
        echo "Message sent!";
?>
```

Comment: usually the webhosting company will allow you to send only a few emails in 1 minute. so, you need to setup a cronjob to do this task each minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to send same email to multiple recipients and that your email addresses are stored in a database, you may do something like this:

1. read email addresses from your database table
2. loop through the email addresses and pass each email address to `$mail->AddAddress();`

This way you can add multiple email addresses to your mail object and then send to all.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using phpmailer, you may [add multiple recipients simply calling `addAddress` multiple times](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#Adding_Multiple_Recipients)...

Obviously, as suggested before, you may want to call this script by mean of a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), thus respecting limits imposed by the mail server.